# How to extract content with search words in html page using Python

Tags: python, html

In html page, having multiple

, Would like to print context with matching words

```
<pre>
currently missing servers:
 vm1 vm2 vm3
currently shutdown servers:
 vm4 vm5 vm6
</pre>
<pre>
Prod server:
 prdvm1 prodvm2
</pre>
```

From above output, would like print only

```
currently missing servers:
  vm1 vm2 vm3
```

Comment: Please give the URL from where you are extracting this data.

Comment: This is internal server, the URL is not publicly accessible. I have to compare the UTC in that webpage with realtime UTC value. I have pasted .html content which URL displays

Answer (score 0):

This answer gives you what you asked based on the html you given.But if the html changes it may not give you proper result.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = ""            #Give your URL here
r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
blockquote = soup.find_all('blockquote')[0]
strong = blockquote.find_all('strong')
for element in strong:
    element.extract()
blockquote = blockquote.text.split(', ')[1].split(' ')[1]
print(blockquote)
```

Comment: It helps, I have changed html5lib to hrml.parser in my setup.  I need to compare real time UTC with extracted utc from above script. I need to create alert if .html UTC time is less than 5min than real time UTC

Comment: ```from datetime import datetime
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "MY_URL"
r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
blockquote = soup.find_all('blockquote')[0]
strong = blockquote.find_all('strong')
for element in strong:
    element.extract()
jprt_time = blockquote.text.split(', ')[1].split(' ')[1]
now = datetime.now()
utc_now = datetime.utcnow()
utc = utc_now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print(utc)
print(jprt_time)
if jprt_time == utc:
  print ("PROD is running fine")
else:
  print("PROD is down")```

Comment: Please format your code. So that it will be useful to others.

Comment: Stackoverflow comment section doesn't allow to format, else I have add my questions as "Answer your question"

Comment: In short, I am trying to use "timedelta" to compare extracted output with realtime and need to send alert if difference is greater than 5 min "if jprt_time < utc - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5):" but getting error as "AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'"

Comment: Issue is resolved after updating timedelta "if jprt_time < utc - timedelta(minutes=5):" instead of "datetime.timedelta"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" >
  <html> 
      <title>PROD> VM</title>
      <h1>Production VM</h1>
      <blockquote> 
          <strong>As of:</strong>Monday September 7, 2020 12:12:35 UTC, Mon-12:12:35-GMT <br>
          <strong>Wiki: <a href="http:proddashboard.com"</a></strong>
   </blockquote>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").find("blockquote").getText()
_time = re.findall(r'\d+:\d+:\d+\sUTC', soup)
print(_time)
```

Output:

```
['12:12:35 UTC']
```

EDIT:

Base on OP's comments here's an updated approach:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" >
  <html> 
      <title>PROD> VM</title>
      <h1>Production VM</h1>
      <blockquote> 
          <strong>As of:</strong>Monday September 7, 2020 12:12:35 UTC, Mon-12:12:35-GMT <br>
          <strong>Wiki: <a href="http:proddashboard.com"</a></strong>
   </blockquote>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").find("blockquote")
result = ''.join(re.findall(r'As of:(.*)\sUTC', soup.getText()))
date = datetime.strptime(result, "%A %B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")

if date < datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=5):
    print("PROD is running")
else:
    print("PROD is not running")
```

Output: `PROD is running`

Comment: Thanks, Using Beatifulsoup if have same tag example <pre>abc</pre>  <pre>def</pre> how can identify with content and print.

Comment: Edit your question with an example HTML and desired output and I'll have a look.

Comment: Also, if you find the answer useful consider up-voting and/or accepting it.

Comment: <pre>
currently missing servers:
  vm1 vm2 vm3
currently shutdown servers:
  vm4 vm5 vm6
</pre>
<pre>
Prod server:
  prdvm1 prodvm2
</pre>

I want to print only "Currently Missing clients
vm1 vm2 vm3"

Comment: I am trying to format HTML but in "Add comment" don't have option to do that

Comment: @Natasha, you realize you can *edit* your question as many times as you want? Add this extra sample in your question, not here.

Comment: Edited my question, please check